# OnMouseUp only works when object is clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmouseup

I have some very simple code that, when an object is clicked (when the mouse is going from pushed to unpushed position), it adds force to an object.  The information on `OnMouseUp` states that

"Note that OnMouseUp is called even if the mouse is not over the same GUIElement or Collider as the has mouse has been pressed down on."

That is exactly what I want.  I want it to activate if I click anywhere on the screen.  It is only working if I click on the object though. Am I misunderstanding something?

Here is the overall code (Very simple):

```
public Rigidbody2D Player;
private void OnMouseUp()
{
     Debug.Log("Test");
     layer.AddForce(transform.up * 1000);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I think it means you *do* have to click on the object but you can release the mouse after moving it and still have the mouse up event triggered for that object.

Comment: Wow now that I read that, that makes complete sense, and I feel kind of dumb.

Comment: @JoeyVagedes I was reading it incorrectly as well! I feel dumb too =P

Comment: Interestingly, I think the opposite is true for standard windows controls like buttons etc, so that might be your source of confusion! (I.e. you can click them but you don't get a mouse up if you move off them before releasing). This may not be right as it's come from observation rather than documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding something?

You got the answer to this under the comment section.

> I want it to activate if I click anywhere on the screen. It is only
>   working if I click on the object though.

`OnMouseUp` is not used for detecting click anywhere on the screen. You need to use one of the `Input.GetMouseButtonXX` functions in the Update function.

Below is likely what you are looking for:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Test");
        Player.AddForce(transform.up * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Other than I want it to be 'Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)' as I want the "Down" part to store power then up to release that power in the force.  But it worked perfectly as you put it. Thank you!

Comment: I see what you are doing. Good you discovered `Input.GetMouseButtonUp` from this. Happy coding!